# Question about messaging passing in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my content script, it's looking for certain keywords in the webpages title. If they are found, I want it to display a notification, using Google's notification API. However, you can't use google's notification API in the content.js - apparently it needs to be in a background file. Any idea how I do this?

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: I've been looking at that but I'm struggling to apply it to my extension. Which bit is relevant for what I'm looking to do ?

Comment: Snippet 1 (sending) and 3 (listening).